# Reference to property '_evolutionURL' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

Tags: json, xcode, alamofire

I'm relatively new to coding and I'm getting stuck with this, I've got a similar one that seems to work which is:

```
    Alamofire.request(_pokemonURL).responseJSON { response in

        if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let name = dict["name"] as? String {

                self._name = name

            }
```

But for some reason, the one below doesn't want to work for me:

```
Alamofire.request(_evolutionURL).responseJSON { response in

                if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    if let evoLvl = dict["min_level"] as? String {

                        self._nextEvolutionLvl = evoLvl

                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What's wrong with adding `self` as suggested? By the way this is Swift. Unlike in Objective-C there are no (backing) instance variables with leading underscores

Comment: I just don't understand why the first one works without adding self but the second one has to add self? I may just be being stupid as I am new to coding.

Also by doing that it gives me another error on some other code:

    Use of unresolved identifier 'dict'